# How to Create Automatic Backup and Long Term Backup In SQL Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am new in SQL Azure and trying to create automatic backup on SQL Azure. But could not found such option for this. I am using free 30 days trial with standard pricing tier. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These questions can be answered by looking at the documentation. SQL Azure has Point-in-Time restore. For databases in the Basic tier there's Point-in-Time restore for 7 days. For Standard it's 14 days and 35 days for Premium.

> All Basic, Standard, and Premium databases are protected by automatic backups. Full backups are taken every week, differential backups every day, and log backups every 5 minutes. The first full backup is scheduled immediately after a database is created.

For long-term backup retention, have a look at [Store Azure SQL Database backups for up to 10 years](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-long-term-retention)

**Edit:**
To learn how to configure long-term retention backup, have a look at [Manage Azure SQL Database long-term backup retention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-long-term-backup-retention-configure)

Comment: actually i want to create automatic backup for my database, so what are the steps ?

Comment: Point-in-Time restore _is_ an automatic backup. Have a look at my edit to find out how to configure long-term retention for backups.